# Time Complexity of loops

Tags: python, big-o, time-complexity

Here is my code. I have to find the time complexity if this code. I gave two answers for this code. one is O(n log(n)) and O(n). But both are wrong. [I gave these answer based on the loop structure. I have seen some codes with for loop within the while loop. and those types of codes have the time complexity of O(n log(n)).]
Can any one suggest me the right answer ?

```
def sort1(lst):
    swapFlag = True
    iteration = 0
    while swapFlag:
        swapFlag = False
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
                temp = lst[i+1]
                lst[i+1] = lst[i]
                lst[i] = temp
                swapFlag = True

        L = lst[:]  # the next 3 questions below refer to this line
        iteration += 1
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some kind of [bubble-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which has time complexity of `O(n^2)`.
Here on every iteration of inner `for` loop you're shifting the maximal element to the end of the list, making `n-1` comparisons. There're `n` elements in the list, and the inner `for` loop will be executed once per each element, giving `O(n^2)`.